# How to terminate R from terminal?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have accidentally closed my machine without clearing a huge Rstudio workspace. Now on starting Rstudio again, it is trying to resume workspace. I have tried killing R session but yet every-time, it starts to load the previous workspace which might take a few days to load. Terminating R will avoid this problem, but only way I know to terminate R is through Rstudio. Is there a way to terminate, not just restart or kill, an R session from terminal. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This link might be helpful - [How to stop a running R command in linux other than ctrl+c?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97968/breaking-from-a-program-running-in-an-interactive-session-in-a-screen-window). All the best!

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Looks like an Rstudio session is different from a R session from terminal. It is still loading the workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, found a workaround from my colleague.

```
cd .rstudio/
rm -r sessions #this will delete the .RData file from session workspace
sudo rstudio-server restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly from terminal you do get the ID of the rstudio process using `ps aux`, and with `sudo kill` you terminate it:

```
panther@panther3:~$ ps aux | grep rstudio
panther   8500  0.1  0.6 2987220 48436 tty1    Sl+  Okt03   3:37 /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio
panther   8553  0.1  1.1 1197924 93320 tty1    Sl   Okt03   3:44 /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rsession --config-file none --program-mode desktop --www-port 12073 --launcher-token 40641CD7 --show-help-home 1
panther   8559  0.0  0.0 333540   988 tty1     S+   Okt03   0:00 /usr/lib/rstudio/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=zygote --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --lang=en-US
panther   8561  0.0  0.0 333540  1076 tty1     S+   Okt03   0:00 /usr/lib/rstudio/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess --type=zygote --webengine-schemes=qrc:sLV --lang=en-US
panther  18891  0.0  0.0  14752  1000 pts/0    S+   14:45   0:00 grep --color=auto rstudio
panther@panther3:~$ sudo kill -9 8500
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: You can clear your workspace using this button]

You can clear your workspace using this button

Comment: Any such action from Rstudio won't work while the session is loading.